# Looking for a search string in a file and storing in a variable - TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to read a file with two variables, username and password, such as:
`user1,password1`

How can I separate the values and store in different variables?
I have tried this but it seems not to store the string itself.

It seems that it can't see the comma in there.
Another idea was to use `\M` to match the "," after every string and store that string but it does not work.

Appreciate some help.

```
set varuser [lsearch -inline -all $userpass "*,"]

set varuser [regexp {,\s+"(.*)"} $userpass all value]
```

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a user's password may contain a comma, I would favour a regex approach:

```
% set line {user1,my,clever,password}
user1,my,clever,password
% lassign [regexp -inline {^(.+?),(.*)$} $line] -> user pass
% set user
user1
% set pass
my,clever,password
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming neither as commas (and ignoring the possible need to trim spaces) `[split]` is simpler than a regexp and may be enough for the task, along with `[lassign]`:

```
tcl> set line {user1,password1}
user1,password1
tcl> lassign [split $line ,] user pwd
tcl> puts $user
user1
tcl> puts $pwd
password1
```

Comment: Just to understand,